# BULK INSERT of Apple EPF Unicode Data Into SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, unicode, bulkinsert

I'm attempting to build an application that will import the Apple EPF feed data into an instance of SQL Server 2012. The data is supplied in flat files, which use CHAR(1) field delimiter and CHAR(2) plus a linefeed (char(10)) as a row delimiter. So a simplified 3-field row would look as follows:

```
field1value[char(1)]field2value[char(1)]field3value[char(2)][linefeed]
field1value[char(1)]field2value[char(1)]field3value[char(2)][linefeed]
```

The files are encoded in UTF-8 and include many different languages, and it's important that all of the data is preserved so down-encoding to ASCII is not an option. However, SQL Server does not support BULK INSERT of UTF-8.

I'm writing this as a C# command line application, and I am pre-processing each file using the following method, which strips comment lines as well as the final newline at the end of the file, and converts the file from UTF-8 to UTF-16:

```
    public void PrepareAppleEPFFile(string dataFilePath, string cleanedFilePath)
{
    if (File.Exists(cleanedFilePath))
        { return; } // Skip processing if file already exists

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataFilePath, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cleanedFilePath, false, Encoding.Unicode))
        {
            string line;
            bool firstLine = true;
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line.Length > 0 && line.Substring(0, 1) != "#") // Skip empty and commented lines
                {
                    // Done this way to avoid adding a trailing newline, which breaks BULK INSERT
                    if (!firstLine)
                    {
                        writer.Write("\n");     
                    }
                    writer.Write(line);
                    firstLine = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once the file is prepared, I use the following BULK INSERT statement:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Application
FROM 'C:\iTunes\data\application.cleaned'
WITH ( 
    TABLOCK,
    DATAFILETYPE =  'widechar',
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\iTunes\Logs\application.log',
    FORMATFILE = 'C:\iTunes\FormatDefinitions\Application.xml'
    )
```

which makes use of the following XML format file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm"  TERMINATOR="\x01\x00"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm"  TERMINATOR="\x01\x00"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm"  TERMINATOR="\x01\x00"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm"  TERMINATOR="\x01\x00"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm"  TERMINATOR="\x01\x00"/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm"  TERMINATOR="\x01\x00"/>
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharTerm"  TERMINATOR="\x01\x00"/>
  <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharTerm"  TERMINATOR="\x01\x00"/>
  <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharTerm"  TERMINATOR="\x01\x00"/>
  <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\x01\x00"/>
  <FIELD ID="11" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\x01\x00"/>
  <FIELD ID="12" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\x01\x00"/>
  <FIELD ID="13" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\x01\x00"/>
  <FIELD ID="14" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\x01\x00"/>
  <FIELD ID="15" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\x01\x00"/>
  <FIELD ID="16" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\x01\x00"/>
  <FIELD ID="17" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\x02"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="application_id" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="title" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="recommended_age" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="artist_name" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="seller_name" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="company_url" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="support_url" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="view_url" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="artwork_url_large" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="11" NAME="artwork_url_small" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="12" NAME="itunes_release_date" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="13" NAME="copyright" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="14" NAME="description" xsi:type="SQLNTEXT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="15" NAME="version" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="16" NAME="itunes_version" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="17" NAME="download_size" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="export_date" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

The above scheme seems to be almost-working, however the data inserted into the table (which uses all NVARCHAR/NTEXT columns) is returned with CHAR(0)'s following each character. So if the value in a column should have been "Bob", what I actually get is "B[char(0)]o[char(0)]b[char(0)]" where [char(0)] of course actually displays as the standard empty-square that is shown for non-printing characters.

[This image shows an example of how the data ends up looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxIIG.png)

The problem is further illustrated by the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 1
DATALENGTH(title) AS DATALENGTH_of_title,
DATALENGTH(cast(title as varchar(1000))) AS DATALENGTH_of_VARCHAR_CAST_Title
FROM dbo.Application
```

For a row with a 7-character title, the above query returns a value of 28 for DATALENGTH_of_title and 14 for DATALENGTH_of_VARCHAR_CAST_Title. These values are double what they should be. BULK INSERT seems to be attempting to re-encode the already unicode data, resulting in double-encoded data where each character is followed by 3 CHAR(0)s instead of just one.

Another, less-serious issue is that writing the data file out in UTF-16 causes a BOM to be added to the beginning of the file, and that BOM sequence ends up getting inserted as part of the first field value in the first row of the file.

I've tried using various values for the CODEPAGE parameter of the BULK INSERT command but none of them have improved the situation, and the ones that did have an effect caused the bulk insert to fail. For example, using CODEPAGE = 1200 (which is the code page for UTF-16) causes the following error:

```
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the 
specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (export_date).
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the problem while reviewing the docs for the XML format file at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187833.aspx

The problem was that I was using **xsi:type="CharTerm"** in the  elements when I should have been using **xsi:type="NCharTerm"**.